# Jerry-rigging a set's elementhood parameters

Tags: set-theory, properties

Suppose one has a bunch of possible elements *x* that satisfy some parameter **P**. Then suppose one tries to get a set *X* that holds all satisfiers of **P**, so all those *x*. Suppose that *X* doesn't itself satisfy **P**, though. So if *X* is an element of itself, it is not on account of satisfying **P**. It is "manually inserted" into itself, so to speak (when it is so inserted). So *X* contains itself and all the *x*; let the *x* be noncircular sets; now *X* is the set of all noncircular sets, is itself circular, but doesn't generate the Russell paradox.

Even without such a "manual insertion" procedure, though, couldn't we jerry-rig the intensional parameters for elementhood, here, say by changing **P** from "noncircular" to "noncircular or identical to *X*"? So if an element *x* is noncircular ***or*** when *x = X*, then *x* is an element of *X*, and again, we have a set containing all noncircular sets but which also contains itself without generating the Russell paradox (*X* is not both inside of, and outside of, itself, but is only inside itself, yet its interiority is not by satisfying the parameter of exteriority, so it is not both interior and exterior to itself).

Or is there some sort of ["revenge"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6394746/) version of that paradox that can be formulated, here? Are [disjunctive properties](https://aardvark.ucsd.edu/metaphysics/dispositions.pdf) omitted from the domain of even the naive comprehension principle?

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:** note that I am ***not*** saying that the Russell set in particular exists, in any world (except maybe a paraconsistent one, but I won't go there right now). The Russell set is such that *all* of its elements *are only* noncircular. Moreover, it has all its elements by them satisfying an exclusive intension. The system I am asking about here would have a set in which all noncircular sets appear but which also has circular elements, which it does *not* have intensionally, or only via a gerrymandered disjunctive intension. Regardless, it has itself as an element but not in a way that means that it satisfies the intension of "noncircular," since obviously it doesn't satisfy that intension. But then the set at issue, here, is not identical to the Russell set of yore, although it is perilously close in essence thereto.

Comment: But that "or" is going to be at least inconvenient in subsequent work, if not inelegant. Disjunctions really make things more complicated.

Comment: @Frank granted, but it is normally supposed that there are absolutely infinitely many noncircular sets, so in my own system, the anticlass principle says that whenever a class contains absolutely many elements of some specific type, it has to contain all elements of all other types, too (this is why I say "anticlass" in that this rules out separate classes of ordinals, cardinals, etc.). So if it is itself an element, it will contain itself, but not because it satisfied some lesser containment parameter. And it will be as complex as possible, since it will be an unrestricted set.

Comment: Russell already showed that you can NOT in general form a set out of the extension of a predicate. So your premises are false. This is your "Then suppose one tries to get a set X that holds all satisfiers of P ..." One immediately gets a contradiction by letting P be the predicate x ∉ x.

Comment: @user4894 the Russell paradox shows that there cannot be a set of all **and only** noncircular sets. Naive separation lets you extract one of these from a universal set, so you have to get rid of naive separation, too. But once those factors are disposed of, one can have a universal set that does have all of some kind of element (but the anticlass principle would require that it have all of *all* kinds of elements).

Comment: That is the point of my remark about manual insertion of elements: if X contains all noncircular sets intensionally, then for a more purely extensional reason it has to contain itself also. If it contained itself for the intensional reason that it contains the noncircular sets, it would have to be itself noncircular, which is impossible, here, so though it does contain itself, this doesn't mean that it satisfies the same intensional parameter of its other elements. So even without the anticlass principle, we can indicate the minimal required structure, here.

Comment: I mainly introduced the anticlass principle into my theory anyway to get around Hamkins' observation that "|ORD| = CARD" would automatically verify a very strong (maybe the strongest, IDK) version of the choice axiom, which verification I would prefer to avoid. But if my system doesn't have CARD and ORD separately (because it has no exclusive classes over those intensions), then the question of their equation is not a real question in the system, and we can say that the ordinals go on to absolute infinity, as do the cardinals, without implying choice (I hope so, anyway).

Comment: @KristianBerry "Naive separation lets you extract one of these from a universal set" There is no universal set. Why do you think there is a universal set? How are you using the phrase?

Comment: @user4894 there's a universal set in Quine's system. [And the usual argument against a universal set is based on Russell's paradox and pushing separation too hard.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755016/universal-set-axiom-of-separation) But as an extralogical axiom, separation can be denied just as well as comprehension. See also Hamkins, Gitman, and Johnstone's essay on [ZFC without the powerset axiom](https://victoriagitman.github.io/files/ZFC-.pdf) for talk of a "largest cardinal."

Comment: Moreover, there is a template for axioms, e.g. dependent choice, such that we can tailor an axiom to "run out eventually," say the general (not global) choice axiom runs out as of Reinhardts, or constructibility runs out as of a specific kind of partition cardinal (or the first uncountable measurable, not for the minimal example but the most intuitively justifed large-cardinal type that involves the existence of zero sharp). So we can say that the separation axiom runs out, and define a set such that its subsets can't be extracted from it by separation (if at all).

Comment: @KristianBerry You're completely mischaracterizing the SE post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755016/universal-set-axiom-of-separation. In fact the PDF lecture notes reference in that question clearly show that they are proving that the Russell set *does not exist*.  Page 9 here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755016/universal-set-axiom-of-separation You are just wrong about your claim. If you're working in Quine set theory you should say so up front.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144717/discussion-between-kristian-berry-and-user4894).